# Powerful Class Structure AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gwt

I want to have the following functionality in AngularJs as I have in C++ or Java(while I used GWT).

I have Class A with list of references to Class B's object and vica-versa so that I can say something like this. A's_object->B's_reference->show_B's_property

```
class A{
list<B*> B_ref;//points to B's class objects
......and more
}

class B{
list<A*> A_ref;//points to A's class objects
......and more
}
```

I mean is it even possible?Please Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs is a framework that uses html, css, and Javascript to easily create single-page applications. Your question would pertain to Javascript rather than the AngularJs framework.

The kind of behavior that you are looking for would be difficult to see in Javascript due to the nature of the language. Javascript is not a language that supports classes in the same way as C++ and Java. Javascript is a dynamic language that is functional based, rather than object oriented.

Javascript can support classes, but not in the same manner as you would be used to in languages like C++ and Java. Javascript instead uses prototypes. Basically, each object has an associated prototype (which is somewhat similar to the static behavior in C++ and Java classes) and this prototype can be decorated with methods and properties. New objects are cloned from existing objects, and the prototypes of the new objects inherits from the original prototype.

This allows many object-oriented features to be imitated in Javascript. I would recommend that you read up about the difference between Javascript and languages like C++.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

```
function A(color) {
  this.bRef = [];
  this.color = color;
  // and more
}

function B(name) {
  this.aRef = [];
  this.name = name;
  // and more
}

var a = new A();
var b1 = new B('foo');
var b2 = new B('bar');

a.bRef.push(b1);
a.bRef.push(b2);

var a1 = new A('red');
var a2 = new A('black');

b1.aRef.push(a1);
b1.aRef.push(a2);

console.log(a.bRef[1].name); // bar
console.log(a.bRef[0].aRef[0].color); // red
console.log(a.bRef[0].aRef[1].color); //black

b2.name = 'boo';

console.log(a.bRef[1].name); // boo
```

Comment: Not actually what I wanted but Thanks it helped somewhat. I think Jonathan is right that we cannot have such functionalities in JS :)